# Make Windows 10 File Explorer look like Mac OSX Finder's column view

Tags: macos, windows-10, mac, windows-explorer, finder

I'm switching from a Mac to a PC with Windows 10. **Is there anyway (either 1st party or 3rd party) to make the File Explorer in Windows 10 look like Finder's column view in Mac OSX?**

Windows 10 File Explorer looks like this:
[image]

MacOSX Finder column view looks like this:
[image]

I don't like how Windows displays a mix of drop down menus (seen in the left column) and standard folders, and I don't like how I can't see all the folders and files in the directories above mine--only in the topmost directory (seen in the lefthand column). This makes it much slower to switch between folders in different subdirectories, especially when you don't remember how many layers deep a file might be.

In contrast, with the Mac OSX Finder column view, all my directories at all levels are clearly visible in neat columns, and you can even enable it to show the path bar at the bottom, just like Windows shows at the top of the File Explorer.

Comment: This won't alter how explorer works, but: open an explorer window, hit win+{left arrow}. Pick the folder you wan to dive into by using right-click+open in new window, win+{leftarrow}. Close the right window when you are done. This will at least preserve the state of the right-hand panes.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [One Commander](http://onecommander.com/), a free third party software.

Screenshot of column view:

[image]

I also found this alternative [Winbrowser](http://www.winbrowser.com/), which doesn't look as slick to me and seems like it's not as actively developed.

Screenshot of WinBrowser column view:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**As of 2021** there is only one option **that doesn't require a third party software** afaik.

1. Open your `File Explorer`.
2. Right-click on `Quick Access` and select `Options`
3. Click on the `View` tab and then scroll down to `Navigation Pane`
4. Select `Expand to open folder` and `Show all folders`

This will provide at least the ability to expand and preview subfolders on your sidebar navigation.

Answer (score 4):

I developed some software to do similar called ThatFile. It has column browser built in.

[ThatFile on Windows App Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/thatfile/9p5nkmfzp3h1?rtc=1#)

Comment: You should probably mention  that it’s not free.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/910319/ebey-tech) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/915801/ebey-tech). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @Scott, Why though? Is it part of the question?

Comment: @SaiManojKumarYadlapati Not sure if it’s mentioned in the rules governing self-promotion, but it stands to reason that when asking someone to give you money, you should mention at some point that you’re asking them to give you money.

Answer (score -1):

There is aprogram called EasyFile. I think it's the best user-friendly and simple solution for windows by now. And it's free at this time. 
The site is in German and I don't know if there's an English Version of the program available. But you could try it at least.

http://tooc.ch/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.